# ffmpeg directory with spaces and '

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm wanting to use FFMEG to merge two video files in the directory E:\Videos\Ryan's Videos\1.mp4 and 2.mp4
 my batch script is:

```
(for %%i in (%*) do @echo file '%%~i') > mylist.txt
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "%cd%\mylist.txt" -c copy "%cd%\output.mp4"
pause
```

this produces the mylist.txt:

```
file 'E:\Videos\Ryan's Videos\2.mp4'
file 'E:\Videos\Ryan's Videos\1.mp4'
```

Which it attempts to read but returns the error

```
[concat @ 00000000026224a0] Impossible to open 'E:\Videos\Ryans'
E:\Videos\Ryan's Videos\mylist.txt: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be tripping up on the ' in the directory when reading from the text file, I've tried containing the paths with " " rather than ' ' however it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: If I were you, I will rename the folder name to avoid special characters and spaces.

Comment: The apostrophy `'` is nothing special to `cmd`, hence this character does not cause any problems. Spaces constitute token separators, hence put double-quotes `"` around file paths/names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - ffmpeg has [unusual quote/escape rules](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping).

I'm not sure how to interpret the rules, but I think one option is to ditch the quotes, and then you need to escape `\` as `\\` and `'` as `\'`

```
file E:\\Videos\\Ryan\'s Videos\\2.mp4
```

The following batch script should give you that result

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>mylist.txt (
  for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "file=%%~F"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "file=!file:\=\\!"
    set "file=!file:'='\!"
    echo file !file!
    endlocal
  )
)
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "%cd%\mylist.txt" -c copy "%cd%\output.mp4"
pause
```

I set the `file` variable with delayed expansion off, and then toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop so as to protect any `!` that may be in the file path.

I left your ffmpeg command as you had it, but I'm pretty sure ffmpeg defaults to the current directory, in which case the line can be simplified to

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Another option that I am more confident about is to preserve the outer quotes, but then the quote must be closed, the apostrophe escaped, and then the quote resumed, which would look like:

```
file 'E:\Videos\Ryan'\''s Videos\2.mp4'
```

The following batch script should give the above result:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>mylist.txt (
  for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "file=%%~F"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "file=!file:'='\''!"
    echo file '!file!'
    endlocal
  )
)
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "%cd%\mylist.txt" -c copy "%cd%\output.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for for that, as @Raptor said I could remove the ' from the path however I don't learn anything from that. also this makes it more versatile when using this in different directories in my PC. Thanks again.